# Working on Fragment Backbutton android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, back-button

I am working on navigation drawer and fragments and currently i am facing a problem from image Consider (Donut) is HomeFragment class. 
What i would like to achieve is

[image: this]

> when user navigate Fragment A(Donut) -> Fragment B(Eclair) then again
>   navigates -> Fragment H(kitkat) and then navigates ->  Fragment
>   I(Lollipop)

and user working on it. If user press backbutton it may 
works based on hierarchy as

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

> As result pressing back results as Fragment I -> Fragment H ->
>   Fragment B -> finally Fragment A.

Now i need to navigate user Directly to Fragment A without going to other Fragment classes.

I have achieved this using

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//initializing 
int check = 0; in MainActivity
....................
...................
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

.................
................

 drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                String aa = tv.getText().toString();
                selectItemFragment(position, aa);
            }
        });

...................
...................
private void selectItemFragment(int position, String aa) {
        Fragment fragment2;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment2 = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment2 = new GalaxyFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment2 = new ShareFragment();
                break;
            default:
                fragment2 = new HomeFragment();
                break;
        }
        check = position;
        ffragm = fragment2;
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment2).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        drawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(aa);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
    }
..........................
............................
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (check == 0) {
            finish();
        } else {
            check = 0;
            Fragment fragment2;
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragment2 = new HomeFragment();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment2).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
}
```

Here i m facing problem,
consider **when user working inside Galaxyfragment class or any other fragment class, he navigates to another fragment class inside, and then he press backbutton it directly navigates to Fragment A.So, here i need to use back stack hierarchy and finally to Fragment Class and finishes the application please see the below code .**

```
public class GalaxyFragment extends Fragment {
    Context cc;
    Button Addbutton;

    public GalaxyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
        ll1design = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.llone);
        Create_list = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.submit);
    Addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                display_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ll1design.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String value = "";
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("message", "" + value);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                Fragment fragment = new ShareFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
  return v;
    }
}
```

So here

> i need to(Achieve) use backbutton to working correctly as Galaxy2Fragment ->
>   GalaxyFragment -> HomeFragment class.

Can anyone give me suggestions how to work on these Backbutton fragments on these type of cases. Suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You can use fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); this to go directly to the bottom of the fragment stack.

Comment: You mean you wish to navigate directly to the 1st fragment from any other fragments opened?

Comment: @Triode thanks, i try using POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE with some logics.

Comment: @PoojaGaikwad yes i need to achieve that and also  need to(Achieve) use backbutton to working correctly as ShareFragment -> GalaxyFragment -> HomeFragment class. something like this

Comment: @Learner - how do you reach till ShareFragment? I am assuming Home-> Galaxy-> Share ? Am I Right?

Comment: @PoojaGaikwad i ll go to Home -> then Galaxy -> then Galaxy2fragment and finally i click the back button it should navigate to Galaxyfragemnt and back to then home fragment. so share fragement is not here sorry,.

Comment: @Learner - I have updated my answer. Try if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest method be to replace this line

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment2).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

to

```
FragmentTransaction ft =fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
ft.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment2)
if(fragmentManger.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment_container) instanceof HomeFragment)
   ft.addToBackStack(null))
ft.commit();
```

You don't required to override onBackPressed if you do this.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting addtobackstack to null . Instead you should write the TAG name of replacing fragment.

**fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();**

instead

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack("**TAG name of an replacing fragment**").commit();
```

Comment: I hope it works for me and your issue gets resolve and if it does then please upvote and accept the answer . Thank you

Comment: @Learner : i am glad your issue gets resolved . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:** 
To navigate directly to the 1st fragment from any other fragments that are opened later

```
private void popByFragment() {
        //keeping only the root fragment in the stack
        int backStackCount = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        for (int i = 1; i < backStackCount; i++) {
            // we start from "i=1" since we dont wish to pop the 1st fragment added to stack
            //Get backstack fragment id
            //Log.e("backstack count", "count-->" + backStackCount);
            int backStackId = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getId();
            mFragmentManager.popBackStack(backStackId, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
}
```

call this method before opening fragments other than **1st fragment**

**Case 2:** Assuming - FragmentC -> FragmentB -> FragmentA.

For this all you have to do is use `fragmentTransaction.addToBackstack(fragment.toString);`
 before commiting.. and then override onBackPress in your activity:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {

            mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    }
```

Make sure you dont call the above method mentioned for "Case1" before commiting this 3 fragments

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
 if (!<titleTextView here>.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("<Title of the First Fragment>")) {
            <Open fragment 1>
            <set the title>

        } else {
            finish();
        }
}
```